# Do I have to rely on JavaScript in order to calculate svg text width?

Tags: javascript, text, svg, width

When I have to calculate the text width of a `<svg>`-`<text>`-element, do I have to rely on JavaScript (with e.g. `getBBox()`)?

I would like to rely on JavaScript as little as possible for core functionality, because people can disable it in their browsers. But I have no clue how to get the width of a `<text>`-element without it, with e.g. php.

Comment: What do you need to calculate it for? What are you doing with the SVG at all? If you need to determine it at the client side, then yes there's no way around js

Comment: I need to draw a box that fits the width of a certain text. And it has to be in svg. For me it does not matter whether it is client side or not. However, I guess there is actually no server side functionality available for calculating the text-width of a svg-text-element. I guess this is partly due to svg-text being dependent on browser fonts etc.